# Adding django view result from ajax as table in template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a django model and I view i am aggregating few columns and filtering result and returning as below

```
def show_grid_summery(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)

    context = {
        "summery": [],
    }

    result = Records.objects.filter(grid_id_id = id).aggregate(Sum('house_count'), Sum('point_count'))
    if len(result) != 0:
        context["summery"].append([result['house_count__sum'], result['point_count__sum']])


    return JsonResponse(context)
```

And on the template i am getting results using ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/summery/',

                    data: {
                      'id': ID
                    },

                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);

                        var trHTML = '';
                        document.getElementById('summaryLabel').innerHTML = '';

                        $.each(data.summery , function (item) {
                            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item[0] + '</td><td>' + item[1] + '</td></tr>';
                        });
                        $('#summaryLabel').append(trHTML);
                    }
```

Now I want to fill the results record (2 columns) as a table inside the #summaryLabel tag. (preferably with headers as well). But I am unable to sort it out after many different attempts.

html part is

```
<table id="summaryLabel">
            <p>information.</p>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you updated with the HTML code? Particularly the code with `#summaryLabel`

Comment: Its just div with id. UPDATED

Comment: What currently happens - do you see rows added to the table? Does the JSON response look correct - does it contain the data you expect (use the network tab in the browser's developer tools to see the response).

Comment: Yes response was coming. I was accessing json with wrong indexing and format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery `$.each()` function passes two parameters, the first is the array index, the second is the object. So it would seem that in your code, your `item` variable would contain the index, which is not what you want.

Try:

```
$.each(data['summery'] , function (i, item) {
    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item[0] + '</td><td>' + item[1] + '</td></tr>';
});
```

or just

```
$.each(data['summery'] , function () {
    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + this[0] + '</td><td>' + this[1] + '</td></tr>';
});
```

jQuery `$.each()` is documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Yes this almost worked. Only I had to use data['summery'] in each function instead of data.summery according to my json response.

Comment: Glad it helped!  I will edit my answer for future searchers.